# How do I paste values and change background color in loop code?

Tags: excel, vba, background-color, copy-paste

I am copying and pasting a range of values that meet conditions from a table to a new sheet using a loop. I'm able to do it with 3 additional lines of code. Is there a better way? I'm fairly new to writing versus recording code and am trying to build my knowledge base.

I'm using Interior.Color (RGB) but I can only change one cell at a time. How do I change all three?

```
For i = 2 To LR
    Worksheets("Multi cut lengths").Activate
    Rng1 = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 17)))
    Rng2 = Cells(i, 21).Value
    Scrap = Cells(i, 23).Value
    OH = Cells(i, 8)
    Rat = Rng1 / Rng2
    scr = Scrap / OH
    If Rat > 0.75 And scr < 0.02 Then
    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
    Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Activate
    Sheets("Cut Sheet").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Cut Sheet").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 239, 218)
    Sheets("Cut Sheet").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 239, 218)
    Sheets("Cut Sheet").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 239, 218)
    End If
Next i
```

It works. I'm just wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: You can use `Resize`.

Comment: There is a better way but will need you to share where these variables were declared

Comment: so replace your last 3 lines with `Sheets("CutSheet").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Resize(0,3).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 239, 218)`

Comment: Thank you both. When I replace the offset with the resize as suggested, I get an "1004 Application-defined or object-defined error on that line. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by BigBen and Miles Fett, you can use the Resize property of the Range object to replace those three lines of code.  Also, you only need to find the last used row once.  And, there's no need to activate your sheet before you paste your value and format your cells.  So your last bit of code can be re-written more efficiently as follows...

```
Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("Cut Sheet")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(lastRow + 1, "a").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Cells(lastRow, "a").Resize(, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 239, 218)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly except I had to add "+ 1" to the second ".Cells line. I don't understand a few things (shortcuts?) in your code. Why do you have ".Cells" instead of just "Cells"? Why use "a" instead of "0" for the column indicator? Thank you in advance

Comment: The `With/End With` construct is used to perform multiple operations on a single object, and the dot in `.Cells` is used to refer to that object. Otherwise, without it, `Cells` would refer to the active sheet instead.

Comment: For the column index, you can use either a letter or a number.  However, in a loop of some sort where the column index will change, you'll want to use a number.  Note that the column index number starts at 1, not 0.